# Implement a ImageView to a SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, imageview, surfaceview, implements

I have one small question...

Is it possible to implement a `ImageView` inside a `SurfaceView`,
or to create a `ImageView` inside the `SurfaceView`

And if so could someone point me in the right direction on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in code with a TextView, but you could just change text view with ImageView.

My TextView is a small bar across the top, hence the changing parameters.

```
      params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      ourSurfaceView = new SurfGame(this);

        testbox = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthx,heighty/30);
    layout.addView(tv,testbox);
    layout.addView(ourSurfaceView,params);
    setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot add child `Views` to a `SurfaceView`.

You can put both an `ImageView` and a `SurfaceView` in some other container, and some containers (`RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`) allow later children to float over top of earlier children (Z-axis ordering). So, you can give the visual appearance of an `ImageView` in a `SurfaceView` that way.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in code I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @toggy-tog-togs: Put the `SurfaceView` in the `RelativeLayout` in XML. Then, at runtime, just call `addView()` on the `RelativeLayout` to add your `ImageView`, using an appropriate `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: can you tell me how to handle click listener on the views which were added to the relative layout , because they are not clickable.